# DefaultDatabase on ShardedDocumentStore

Tags: ravendb

On a standard `DocumentStore` we can specify the default database to use as:

```
documentStore = new DocumentStore {
    DefaultDatabase = "Comics"
}
```

How do we go about doing the same for a `ShardedDocumentStore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the answer is quite obvious now.

The `DefaultDatabase` can be set on each of the individual shards that are set up before the `SharededDocumentStore` is created.

```
var shards = new Dictionary<string, IDocumentStore>
                 {
                      { "Marvel", new DocumentStore { 
                                          Url = "http://localhost:8080", 
                                          DefaultDatabase = "Comics" } 
                      },
                      { "DC Comics", new DocumentStore { 
                                          Url = "http://localhost:8081", 
                                          DefaultDatabase = "Comics" } 
                      }
                 };
```